# Can i use K2 Blackpearl without SharePoint?

Tags: .net, sharepoint, business-process-management, k2

is it possible to develop a solution using .NET technology along with a the K2 Blackpearl BPM but without using **Microsoft SharePoint** ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely. In fact K2 was built originally to work with web pages only - SharePoint integration was added later (although it is an core part of the product now).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, K2 Blackpearl can be used in any workflow process independently from SharePoint. K2 BlackPoint on the other hand can only be used for SharePoint workflows.